# How can I resolve the Class type for generic parameter, when the parameter value is being passed as an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

Consider a method with the following signature:

```
void foo(List<T> myList) ...
```

Let's assume, by using reflection, you need to construct such a function and obtain the `PropertyInfo` details of the `T` type parameter.  Calling `typeof(T).GetProperties(...)` should do the trick, so we can add the following line to our method, to obtain these details.

```
void foo(List<T> myList)
{
    PropertyInfo[] props = 
        typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public 
            | BindingFlags.Instance 
            | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

    ...
}
```

This provides the information we need... except when `T` is an interface parameter, what I'm finding is that `props` only contains the interface properties and not the properties associated with class that is within the list, which inherits from the interface.

To be clear, my interface AND my class definitions are public, as are the properties within my classes.

How can I get the properties associated with the actual type that inherits an interface rather than strictly the interface properties?

Comment: if T is an interface, then myList can contains objects of different actual types.

Comment: Yes, so is this not possible? My actual scenario is I have a method that returns a `List<IMyInterface>` which I need to use.  After obtaining the list and molding some of the similar properties, I need to pass the list into a more generic function (one that takes a `List<T>` and I need to iterate over all of the properties.  The properties can be flattened, but I need access to all of them, at least as defined from the interface AND within the class definitions.

Comment: *“what I'm finding is that props only contains the interface properties”* – of course; the generic type parameter `T` is evaluated at compile time, so there is nothing that can depend on the *content* of that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a flat list of all object properties contained inside the `List<T>`, here's a LINQ solution:

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties =
                          myList.SelectMany(x => x.GetType()
                                                  .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | 
                                                                 BindingFlags.Instance));
```

If you need to access the declaring type, you can always look `PropertyInfo.DeclaryingType`

If you don't want a flat list, `Select` can do:

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo[]> properties =
                            myList.Select(x => x.GetType()
                                                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | 
                                                               BindingFlags.Instance));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the actual type, you probably need to get it for each item:

```
foreach (T t in myList)
{
    Type itemType = t.GetType();

    itemType.GetProperties(...)
    // etc.
}
```

You can also add specific code for different types with:

```
if(itemType == typeof(MyConcreteType))
{
    // do specific stuff for that type
}
```